# Is there a way to turn off scoring when searching in Elasticsearch, to gain performance?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I have over 33 million records in my Elasticsearch 7.1 index and when I query it, I limit the result size to 20. However, ES still scores the records internally. But this isn't important for me and in fact, I want *any* 20 results. So, for example I don't care if some of the results are more relevant.

My question is, is there a way to turn this behaviour off, and if so, will it improve the performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `_doc` as a sort field. This will make ES return the fields sorted in the order of insertion, and hence it will not do scoring.

Here is a thread from the forums that explains more:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/most-efficient-way-to-query-without-a-score/57457/4

Answer (score 0):

From the [Sort search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html#sort-search-results) section of the Elasticsearch docs (as of 8.8):

> `_doc` has no real use-case besides being the most efficient sort order. So if you don’t care about the order in which documents are returned, then you should sort by `_doc`. This especially helps when scrolling.

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 1000,
  "track_total_hits": false,
  "query": {...},
  "sort": ["_doc"]   # <------- THIS.
}
```

You should see the `max_score` and `_score` fields in the results as `null`.